# Can I invoke MethodHandle.invokeExact from ByteBuddy?

Tags: byte-buddy

[`MethodHandle#invokeExact(Object...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/invoke/MethodHandle.html#invokeExact(java.lang.Object...)) is a strange method in Java.

Suppose I wanted to invoke this from ByteBuddy (using `MethodCall.invoke()` and the like).  Is there a way to do this without incurring a runtime exception?  (Please bear in mind in any answers to this question that although it *looks* like it takes an ordinary `Object` array, `MethodHandle#invokeExact(Object...)` treats that argument *very* unusually.)

Answer (score 1):

Those methods have a polymorphic signature and expect the arguments to be of the expected types, against the actual class file signature. Unfortunately, this corner case of method invocation is not supported in Byte Buddy at this day.

Comment: Thanks. I did see the `StackManipulation` subtype of [`HandleInvocation`](https://javadoc.io/static/net.bytebuddy/byte-buddy/1.10.19/net/bytebuddy/implementation/bytecode/member/MethodInvocation.HandleInvocation.html) and I thought perhaps there was some way of using that directly?

Comment: The simplest way would be to implement your own StackManipulation where you invoke invokeExact using ASM. I can look into how to support it in Byte Buddy at some point but it's such a corner case, I won't prioritize it just now.

Comment: I realize that I was making it too complicated anyway.  I found the [`InvokeDynamic`](https://javadoc.io/static/net.bytebuddy/byte-buddy/1.10.19/net/bytebuddy/implementation/InvokeDynamic.html) class and it worked great.  It's really easy to use; nicely done! 